# If $f$ is a real valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\{x|f(x)=a\}$ is measurable for each $a\in\mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ be an extended real valued function on $E$. Then $f$ is measurable if $\forall a\in\mathbb{R},\{x\in E|f(x)<a\}$ is measurable.

Is it the case that, if $f$ is a real valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\{x|f(x)=a\}$ is measurable for each $a\in\mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is measurable? My gut tells me that it is not necessarily the case. I cannot find a counterexample though. Could someone give me a hint? Thanks.

**Attempted solution** (*added later*):
Consider the non-measurable set $\mathcal{N}$ defined on the interval $[0,1]$ using the "rational-relation". Take
$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x & \text{if $x\in \mathcal{N}$}\\
x+2 & \text{if $x\in(\mathbb{R}-\mathcal{N})\bigcap [0,1]$}\\
x+100 & \text{if $x>1$}\\
x & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}$,

and observe that $f^{-1}((0,1))=\mathcal{N}$ is not measurable.

Is this solution alright?

Comment: No, this is not true. I encourage you to construct a counterexample. To do this, use the non-measurable set that you already know of (which is the Vitali construction, I presume). Try to make, for every $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, a function $f$ such that $\{f(x) = \alpha\}$ has either one point or no points, but maybe the preimage of the set $[0,1]$ or something could be non-measurable.

Comment: Thanks. I added a solution and could you please check?

Comment: I think it looks fine.